# react-navigation child component data to parent component function [react-navigation 5]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[i'm new in react-native.]

how do i pass child component data to parent component function in react-navigation 5

suppose i navigate to child component from parent component **parent.jsx** by

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ChildComponentScreen');
```

i have a function in **parent.jsx** component

```
parentFunction = (data) => {

}
```

how i called parentFunction in **parent.jsx** from **child.jsx** component with data.

Comment: Parent and child are two screen in the same stack right ?

Comment: yes my parent screen (DashboardScreen) and child screen (NewClientScreen) in same stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function as a parameter to the next screen(ChildScreen) like below

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  sendData = (data) => {
    alert(data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ChildComponent', {
              sendData: this.sendData,
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And call it from the child screen like below

```
class ChildScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.route.params.sendData('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but problem is that i used both as class component and it's how me send data is not define but i already declared.

Comment: only change will be this.props.route.params.sendData and in navigation you will have to pass a the function like this.sendData in params

Comment: @RanaJahid updated to class based component, please check